# Making classes within classes communicate

Tags: python, class, python-3.x

I'm coming from JavaScript into Python and encountered a problem I'm unable to solve.

I have a main controller like this:

```
from TVcontroller import TVController

class MainController(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.TVControllers = []
        self.TVControllers.append(TVController("VardagsrumsTV"))
        self.TVControllers.append(TVController("Köks TV"))
        print("Welcome to the TV-simulator")

 ...
```

It creates new `TVController` instances from:

```
from TV import TV

class TVController(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.TV = TV(name)

    def exit(self):
       #I WANT TO INVOKE A FUNCTION ON MY PARENT!

...
```

I want my `TVController` to be able to tell the `MainController` when it is exited.
In JavaScript I would just write some `"on,event, do-this"` function. How is this handled in Python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option would be to make a `TVController` hold a reference to its `master` (I would avoid the term `parent`, as this often implies inheritance) `MainController` instance:

```
class TVController(object):

    def __init__(self, name, master=None):
        self.TV = TV(name)
        self.master = master

    def exit(self):
        if self.master is not None:
            self.master.... # whatever
```

Then create them like:

```
class MainController(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.TVControllers = []
        self.TVControllers.append(TVController("VardagsrumsTV", self))
        self.TVControllers.append(TVController("Köks TV", self))
        print("Welcome to the TV-simulator")
```

Comment: This seems like EXACTLY what i needed. Big thanks. I really miss events from Javascript :(

Comment: Nothing prevents you from doing events in Python :-)